# npm install error: Receiving Fork Errors: "died waiting for dll loading, errno 11"

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, angular-cli

If anyone can help, that would really be appreciated.  I've struggled for several days on this.  This is occurring when I'm trying to install the angular-cli.  Here are some details before I list the errors:

- git version: git version 2.10.0.windows.1
- npm version: 3.10.3
- node version: 6.7.0
- OS: Windows 7

I've reinstalled git and npm and had removed my npm and npm cache temporary directories.  I ran `npm cache clean` and I'm not using `cygwin`.  Here's the command tool output:

```
c:\UserName>npm install -g angular-cli
```

and it throws following log trace

```
0 [main] sh 3376 fork: child 9600 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11

1174145 [main] sh 3376 fork: child 2284 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11

3329182 [main] sh 3376 fork: child 9600 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11

7442066 [main] sh 3376 fork: child 4980 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11

15588854 [main] sh 3376 fork: child 5860 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 1
1
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:       0 [main] sh 3376 fork
: child 9600 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 1174145 [main] sh 3376 fork
: child 2284 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 3329182 [main] sh 3376 fork
: child 9600 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 7442066 [main] sh 3376 fork
: child 4980 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 15588854 [main] sh 3376 for
k: child 5860 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:
      0 [main] sh 9524 fork: child 5224 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11

1148619 [main] sh 9524 fork: child 780 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
3301794 [main] sh 9524 fork: child 1400 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11

7457442 [main] sh 9524 fork: child 6692 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11

15573833 [main] sh 9524 fork: child 780 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11

npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:       0 [main] sh 9524 fork
: child 5224 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 1148619 [main] sh 9524 fork
: child 780 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 3301794 [main] sh 9524 fork
: child 1400 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 7457442 [main] sh 9524 fork
: child 6692 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 15573833 [main] sh 9524 for
k: child 780 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:
      0 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 10780 - died waiting for dll loading, errno
11
1179978 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 5152 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 1
1
3312996 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 8700 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 1
1
7434899 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 11256 - died waiting for dll loading, errno
11
15600517 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 10492 - died waiting for dll loading, errno
 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:       0 [main] sh 10568 for
k: child 10780 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 1179978 [main] sh 10568 for
k: child 5152 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 3312996 [main] sh 10568 for
k: child 8700 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 7434899 [main] sh 10568 for
k: child 11256 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry: No child processes
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: 15600517 [main] sh 10568 fo
rk: child 10492 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: C:\Applications\Git\mingw64
/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code 254

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true submodule -q update --init -
-recursive
npm ERR!       0 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 10780 - died waiting for dll loadin
g, errno 11
npm ERR! C:\Applications\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry
: No child processes
npm ERR! 1179978 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 5152 - died waiting for dll loading
, errno 11
npm ERR! C:\Applications\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry
: No child processes
npm ERR! 3312996 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 8700 - died waiting for dll loading
, errno 11
npm ERR! C:\Applications\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry
: No child processes
npm ERR! 7434899 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 11256 - died waiting for dll loadin
g, errno 11
npm ERR! C:\Applications\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: retry
: No child processes
npm ERR! 15600517 [main] sh 10568 fork: child 10492 - died waiting for dll loadi
ng, errno 11
npm ERR! C:\Applications\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: fork: Resou
rce temporarily unavailable
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\...\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your command line as Administrator and run following command

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

**Note:** `angular-cli` downloads too many dependencies that may take time. It would be better to have good internet speed

Comment: Thanks, Arif.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same errors.  I tried through my phone hotspot: Mbps: 23.8 download, 3.85 Mbps upload and my home wifi: Mbps: 4.46 download, 2.29 Mbps upload and through our company's hardwired network which I am guessing is faster than both.  Also, I haven't noticed any other occasions when internet speed seems to be questionable.  Please let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: So, I wonder if this is a network error (which for reasons above make me less convinced), git error, npm error?  I'm wondering where to even start debugging.  I found that Windows 7 has a program called eventvwr.  I looked through that a bit to see if I could find evidence of networking or other system errors, but nothing stood out for the time I ran the npm install command.  Any ideas for where to even focus?  Thx.